# How can I re-write feeds xpathparser data?

Tags: feeds

I have a feed content type with an author(s) field. Some of the nodes have several authors, so I am able to explode the data into an array with feeds tamper. However, I'd also like to re-write the author entries from LAST_NAME, FIRST_NAME to FIRST_NAME LAST_NAME. Before I dive into writing a plugin, I was wondering if there were another option for this, it seems like a common use case.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the REGEX find/replace plugin in Feeds Tamper to do it.

Find: `([^,]+),\s*([^,]+)`

Replace: `$2 $1`

Note: The above regex is more-or-less a guess and assumes that there are no commas in the FIRST_NAME or LAST_NAME.